# can a vector of strictly positive values have a negative autocorrelation at any lag?

Tags: autocorrelation

matlab is giving some weird results.

I have a vector of nonnegative numbers which is the duration between subsequent events. I calculate the autocorrelation of this and plot it, and after about lag 100 it turns negative...

the source data is here
[image]

and the autocorrelation is here

[image]

Comment: Can the correlation between two non-negative random variables be negative?

Comment: @MossMurderer I don't think so but if I knew that I wouldn't be asking

Comment: As one increases, the other decreases. Why would that be restricted to variables that can have negative values?

Comment: The correlation formula is $r = \frac{\sum{(x-m_x)(y-m_y)}}{\sqrt{\sum{(x-mx)^2}\sum{(y-my)^2}}}$ how can it be negative if no element of the input vectors x and y are negative? actually I see how it could be..  I've just never encountered a process with these characteristics... Interesting

Comment: If x tends to be above/below $m_x$ when y is below/above $m_y$, then the numerator is a sum over mostly negative values.

Comment: I don't know what the data is exactly but that ACF shape is usually a sign that the series in not stationary in the mean. Could there be a reason why the mean is varying over time ? It seems okay that you would have a linear relationship that decreases over time but that it changes sign and continues that way seems odd to me.

Comment: @mlofton If this acf were continued to larger lags, it would look like a damped sine wave, reflecting the pseudo-periodicity in the underlying data.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Not sure how you know that but it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton whuber is right if I calculate more lags it does show as a damped sign wave. This series is the inter-trade duration between buys of XBTUSD on the bitmex exchange for about a 4 hour period. The mean duration is about 4 seconds

Comment: @crow. thanks for perspective. whuber: your answer was  interesting  because I joined dspSE a couple of years back to begin to learn the basics of DSP ( because there's a lot of overlap with time-series topics ). I'm still  a total beginner but since it came up here, I'll ask. The time domain acf is  approximately a damped sine wave (at some  frequency). My question is:  Can we infer then  the frequency coefficients of the DFT of the original data ? My poor DSP intuition would make me think that it implies one frequency component in the DFT of the actual series ? Is that correct ?  Thanks.

Comment: correction: actually 2 components because there would be one at $-\omega$ and one at $\omega$ because of the complex variable usage in the DFT.

Comment: I think this type of pattern also happens if the number of lags gets too close o the number of samples in the series

Answer (score 2):

> can a vector of strictly positive values have a negative autocorrelation at any lag?

[NB As whuber notes, the question is ambiguous. I read it as "With positive time series, can there be a lag at which there's a negative correlation?".]

Consider the sequence $Y_t =12/Y_{t-1}$ with $Y_0=4$.

Alternatively, consider $Y_t=10-Y_{t-1}$ with $Y_0=4$.

As a more prosaic but realistic example, take some stationary series that has a  negative correlation at some lag and shift it up by some large value $L$ (some value easily large enough to make the whole series positive). The autocorrelations are unchanged.

Or take a series with a strong negative correlation and little noise that's close to zero (but can be both positive and negative) and exponentiate it. For example:

```
 x <- arima.sim(n=1000,list(ar=-.9),sd=.01)
 y <- exp(x)
 acf(y)
```

Any of these should suffice to demonstrate that negative autocorrelations are easily attained with positive variates.

Comment: It's unclear which question you are answering, Glen: the answer to the question in the title, which can be understood as "can a vector of positive values have negative autocorrelation coefficients at *all nonzero lags*," would be a little different.

Comment: @whuber I'm answering "With positive time series, can there be a lag at which there's a negative autocorrelation?" which is how I read the title, though I agree it's ambiguous. I'll put a clarification in my answer.